# Excel cells evaluating blanks incorrectly

Tags: error-handling, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have some cells in an Excel 2007 file that perform `SUMPRODUCT()` operations over a range (lets call it `RANGE2`) of cells that have if statements in them. The `IF()` statements are similar to the following:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(RANGE1), *mathematical operation on RANGE1*, "")
```

In other words, I want to

Since I put the `""` in the if statements, the cells that `sumproduct` over `RANGE2` produce `#VALUE!` errors.

Is there a way around this? I would like to get numerical results from this evaluation.

**Edit 1**
I have graphs that are drawn using the numbers from Range1 and Range2. If I use 0's instead of "", the graphs will tend to zero and will be misleading.

Comment: Can you just use 0 instead of ""?

Comment: I have graphs that are drawn using the numbers from Range1 and Range2. If I use 0's, the graphs will be misleading. I should have mentioned this in the question, I'll edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to clarify - are all the results of the `sumproduct` producing the error or only the ones that are attempting to add the `""` values?

If you just need to hide the errors, you can use

```
=IFERROR(<existing formula here>,"")
```

Comment: Hi there, I don't need to hide the error, only to find a way to perform mathematics on numerical values and ignore "" values. I've already tried IFERROR() but it only provided a bandaid solution I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried to recreate your error but it works fine for me. Without seeing more detail, all I can suggest is to make sure that all the cells in the data range for your sumproduct are in number format. Text formatted cells can cause #VALUE! errors.

Comment: I've done this as well, but the error still persists.